# Updating timestamps in a document in [HH:MM:SS] format?

Tags: ruby, timestamp

I'm unfamiliar with Ruby, but I have a script that was written for me that I'm trying to modify. The script right now replaces timestamps in a document with an offset, with the timestamps in HH:MM format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

h, m, = 12, 07
$_.gsub!(/(\d\d):(\d\d)/) do
  '%02d:%02d' % (($1.to_i + h) * 60 + $2.to_i + m).divmod(60)
end
```

I'd like to just add a seconds field to the offset, so that I can find and update timestamps in HH:MM:SS format. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the ability to revise/rewrite a time expressed as `HH:MM:SS` by rewriting the code you have can be simplified by understanding what the current code does.

First, lets look at this line and decipher what it does,

```
$_.gsub!(/(\d\d):(\d\d)/) do
```

The `$_` is the input line, which you are processing using the `gsub!` function.

The regular expression, `/(\d\d):(\d\d)/`, says match two digit pairs, separated by a colon (':'), and the parenthesis around the digit pairs says copy them into variables named `$1` and `$2`, which are used later.

Since you want to detect and process `HH:MM:SS`, you need to revise your regular expression to detect this pattern, `/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/`, which will store the `HH` into `$1`, `MM` into `$2`, and `SS` into `$3`, respectively.

Here is what the line would look like, revised to add a third match for seconds,

```
$_.gsub!(/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/) do
```

The next line does several computations, and prints the result into a string using the `%` format specifier.

```
  '%02d:%02d' % (($1.to_i + h) * 60 + $2.to_i + m).divmod(60)
```

The first expression, `($1.to_i + h) * 60`, converts the first matched `\d\d` to integer, and then adds the value of `h=12`, and then multiples by `60`.

The second expression, `$2.to_i + m`, converts the second matched `\d\d` to integer, and then adds the value of `m=07`.

The `divmod(60)` produces a list with two elements, corresponding to the integer division by `60`, and the integer remainder of division by `60`. This is unnecessary, and is only used to detect and move overflow from the minutes offset into the hours element.

Since you want to add seconds, you may want to handle a seconds offset, and the following will handle the overflow from seconds and then from minutes,

```
hour, min, sec = [ $1.to_i + h, $2.to_i + m, $3.to_i + s ]
if sec >= 60 then min += 1; sec -=60; end #only needed if s > 0
if min >= 60 then hr += 1; min -=60; end #must do before seconds offset
'%02d:%02d:%02d' % [hour, min, sec]
```

Assembling the above together,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

h, m, s = 12, 07, 13
$_.gsub!(/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/) do
  hour, min, sec = [ $1.to_i + h, $2.to_i + m, $3.to_i + s ]
  if sec >= 60 then min += 1; sec -=60; end #only needed if s > 0
  if min >= 60 then hr += 1; min -=60; end #must do before seconds offset
  '%02d:%02d:%02d' % [hour, min, sec]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you don't want the overhead of instantiating a Time object, you could just append the :00 in the end of the resulting string:</s>

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

h, m, s = 12, 07, 10
$_.gsub!(/(\d\d):(\d\d)/) do
   '%02d:%02d' % (($1.to_i + h) * 60 + $2.to_i + m).divmod(60) + ":#{s}"
end
```

Maybe something like this will work:

```
require 'time'

h,m,s= "09:30:03".split(':').map(&:to_i) # h,m,s = 9,30,3  would work here too

$_.gsub! /\[(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\]/ do
    # time is in seconds so multiply by 60 to get minutes' seconds
    # and again to get hours'
    t = Time.parse($1) + (h * 60 * 60) + (m * 60) + s
    "[#{t.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}]"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd love to actually be able to input a value for the seconds field too, and update all of the hh:mm:ss fields of the time stamps accordingly. The overhead doesn't matter much to me; I'm just updating a handful of text files. What would that script look like?

Comment: I guess what I'm hoping to understand is, where do the offsets come from? Will they be different for each time stamp?  Arbitrary? Do you want random seconds, the same seconds each time, or to pass specific seconds in for each stamp?

Comment: Does the edited answer do what you mean, @user260467 ?

Comment: I thought that the input string doesn't have seconds yet and you want to add them?  I'm afraid I'm a little confused, maybe.

Comment: That seems to be adding in the following way: `hh:mm:00:ss`. I'm looking for `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Can you give me a full time stamp and your expected output?

Comment: Starting example timestamp would be `[00:02:00]`, and I would like to add `[09:30:03]`, for an output of `[09:32:03]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is very close, but for some reason, inputting `09` for h returns `10`. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, your script malfunctioned, as described in my comment above.

Comment: As I said, it was a typo and it is fixed.